# How can I raise the output temperature of my air conditioner for better comfort?

Tags: air-conditioning

I think they put too much refrigerant because it's too cold at night; it is not comfortable. It's freezing cold even at 75 degrees.

What can I do? This is a newly installed ac and furnace.

Comment: Some information about your HVAC system and home would be helpful. Please revise to tell us more.

Comment: What type of system are we talking? Is this a whole home system, a split system , or a room window unit. I have heard this complaint from all in the past. I would lean to an air handler with compressor for the home since you said furnace but want to make sure. And the brand/ model. It may be as easy as adjusting your fan speed up so the air is not as cold.

Comment: Ac and furnace carrier brand

Comment: Fan speed ok ill ask my company technical guy

Comment: What is the approximate temperature difference between the air at your return vents and what's coming out of your supply vents?  I've always believed that a good rule-of-thumb is to look for about a 20 degree F difference between return and supply temps on AC.  If you're in that temperature range ballpark, it's cooling fine and you need to look elsewhere for issues.  (I do encourage HVAC professionals to correct me if I'm wrong on that "rule-of-thumb" for a layperson checking AC performance.)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't too much refrigerant in the unit. It doesn't work that way. Check your thermostat setting and verify its accuracy with another cheap thermometer. Readjust the directional settings of your AC registers so they're not blowing directly on you. Restrict their flow by closing them a bit, they are fully adjustable. Be thankful it's cold; most people complain their AC doesn't get cold enough.

Comment: Australians? It was 97 deg. F in Alice Springs today.

Comment: You do not want to restrict the flow that will make it colder and cause icing. I do agree that there is not to much refrigerant , and re directing it the best option.

Comment: @EdBeal  OK, how about re balancing the air flow.  The flow rate is adjustable.

Comment: Possibly, if an air handler with a multi speed motor I would bump the speed in cooling mode up, this will reduce the temp drop and may improve efficiency trying for super cold discharge is good for a freezer but not a home.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm confused.  I've adjusted the flow on hundreds of AC units  through the adjustments on the registers.  One room is too cold, the other is too hot. I'd close the one vent a bit, and open the other  more..... everyone is now happy. .. no icing.

Comment: In general if the discharge temp is two cold there are 3 or 4 things that can be done, easy bump the air flow increases output temp, harder   Move the evaporator sensor. Hardest adjust the flow by changing orifice or throttle adjustment in a txv. All may work , if just 1 room is cold maybe vent adjustments will work but my experience is with super cold a system adjustment of flow of air across the coil increased or flow of refrigerant reduced to the coil will be needed for extreme cold.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple possibilities. First is that your new air conditioner is oversized. That's not uncommon, as HVAC contractors would rather err on the side of too much heat or cooling since that results in fewer callbacks. I'd investigate that (compare the unit's rating with the size of your home), and if it is oversized, address that with your contractor.

Another is that airflow is restricted somehow. The less air that travels over the coil, the more its temperature is reduced. Be sure that all vents are open in rooms you'd like cooled, and that nothing is covering them. Also check the return vents. You want as free a flow path as possible.

Finally, look into deflectors for the vents. They'll let you direct the cool air somewhere that doesn't result in discomfort.

Comment: The AC is normal since in backyard the furnace in garage is bigger than the old one

Comment: I really have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Too much refrigerant is not the issue.

Instead it should controlled by a thermostat that tries to reach a set temperature. Change the temperature to something more comfortable.

Or move its temperature sensor to somewhere reasonable so that it actually measures the room's temperature.

You can also simply turn off the unit at night and save yourself some power that way.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the output air is too cold to be comfortable. It's not a matter of room temperature, but draft temperature.

Comment: This thermostat problem this the furnace or ac to amped up for cold in a small house ok